# Propellant less propulsion when there is nothing to push against

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, mass, inertia, propulsion

Is there a way for a vehicle to move without losing mass when there is nothing for the vehicle to push against? For example, a helicopter flying around in a vacuum.

Comment: You are asking if a reactionless drive is possible. In addition to reading the [wikipedia article on reactionless drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionless_drive), search for [reactionless drives](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=reactionless+drive) here on Physics Stack Exchange. For example, your question is close to a duplicate of [Is it possible to move without throwing or pushing another object or energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/707540/is-it-possible-to-move-without-throwing-or-pushing-another-object-or-energy/707657).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as you require not acceleration, inertia will carry your vehicle forever.

Or:
No. I translate "nothing for the vehicle to push against" as "nothing the vehicle can exert a force on". And then by Newton's "actio est reactio" there is nothing to exert a force on the vehicle and thus to accelerate it.